How to request for an oplock from linux client?
I am learning on Samba, I have gone through the documentation on oplock feature now on my local(Ubuntu) i created a SMB server with default config (oplock enabled) when i access this share from Windows i can see on create file requests batch oplock being called in Wireshark but when i mount this share over ubuntu i can see create request file with oplock: No. Is oplock a windows specific feature ? How do i make a read file/ create file request while being on a linux client.Here is my smb.conf file
[custom_share]
        browseable = yes
        path = /
        read only = no
        writeable = yes
        guest ok = no

